# About cross-browser tricks

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I've got a great [jQuery plugin](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) that allows you to insert browser-specific CSS into your stylesheet.

EXAMPLE:

```
#foo {width: 100%; border: 12px solid white}
.opera #foo {width: 99%; border: 12px solid red}
.gecko #foo {width: 33%; border: 12px solid blue}
```

...you get the idea.

QUESTION:

Is there something similar that can be used to insert browser-specific jQuery snippets, or even browser specific HTML? For example, (pseudo-code): IF opera, fadeIn div#opera, IF webkit fadeIn div#webkit, etc.

I'm trying to figure out how to make, for example, a pop-up which appears only for Opera, and another that is only for Webkit, etc.

Basically, post anything you have that helps target specific browsers, as I want to learn everything I need to know. I'm looking for plugins that help make cross-browser tasks easier, and I'm not too concerned about older browsers.

UPDATE:

Here's the plugin I'm using:

```
function css_browser_selector(u) {
var ua = u.toLowerCase(),
    is = function (t) {
        return ua.indexOf(t) > -1
    }, g = 'gecko',
    w = 'webkit',
    s = 'safari',
    o = 'opera',
    m = 'mobile',
    h = document.documentElement,
    b = [(!(/opera|webtv/i.test(ua)) && /msie\s(\d)/.test(ua)) ? ('ie ie' + RegExp.$1) : is('firefox/2') ? g + ' ff2' : is('firefox/3.5') ? g + ' ff3 ff3_5' : is('firefox/3.6') ? g + ' ff3 ff3_6' : is('firefox/3') ? g + ' ff3' : is('gecko/') ? g : is('opera') ? o + (/version\/(\d+)/.test(ua) ? ' ' + o + RegExp.$1 : (/opera(\s|\/)(\d+)/.test(ua) ? ' ' + o + RegExp.$2 : '')) : is('konqueror') ? 'konqueror' : is('blackberry') ? m + ' blackberry' : is('android') ? m + ' android' : is('chrome') ? w + ' chrome' : is('iron') ? w + ' iron' : is('applewebkit/') ? w + ' ' + s + (/version\/(\d+)/.test(ua) ? ' ' + s + RegExp.$1 : '') : is('mozilla/') ? g : '', is('j2me') ? m + ' j2me' : is('iphone') ? m + ' iphone' : is('ipod') ? m + ' ipod' : is('ipad') ? m + ' ipad' : is('mac') ? 'mac' : is('darwin') ? 'mac' : is('webtv') ? 'webtv' : is('win') ? 'win' + (is('windows nt 6.0') ? ' vista' : '') : is('freebsd') ? 'freebsd' : (is('x11') || is('linux')) ? 'linux' : '', 'js'];
c = b.join(' ');
h.className += ' ' + c;
return c;
};
css_browser_selector(navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: You should never detect browser. You should detect features. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: "I've got a great jquery plugin" care to share with us?

Comment: (Yep. plugin link and the code itself added to original post.)

Comment: I keep hearing "you should never detect browser" and "use modernizr", but I'm just not ready to learn those things yet. I need easy quick fixes.

Comment: Modernizr counts as an easy quick fix. Just include and then test one globally visible variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all this plugin does is to append several classes to the `html` tag. To test them using jQuery, you can do

```
$html = $("html"); //cached for performance reasons
...

if( $html.is(".gecko") ){
  ...
```

. Better yet, look if the plugin also sets some global (or visible from the global scope) variables that you can use directly. It is likely the case.

Also, please don't ever look at what the browser *is* when you want to know what the browser *can do*. Feature-detect, not browser-detect (unless the feature cannot be reliably detected, as noted by DCoder). The [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library can be used for that.

Comment: When I view source I don't see any classes added to html or body tags, but perhaps the plugin can be modified to do so.

Comment: @user1691389 some classes need to be added somewhere for the plugin to work. It seems to be `html` as per this example: `html.gecko div#header { margin: 1em; }`

Comment: the classes are added in the stylesheet. Hmm, maybe I could add the classes myself on the body elem's.

Comment: If you look at the DOM of the plugin page you will see (for example) `<html ... class=" webkit chrome win js">`

Comment: I agree with the Modernizr sentiment in general, but there are exceptions. One example from personal experience: when using a certain @font-face, rendering on screen is okay, when trying to print, Chrome and Safari silently use Times New Roman instead of the custom font or the sans-serif fallback given in CSS. Detecting a user agent was needed to set a better font for those browsers. Detect *that* `:)` ( @user1691389: view source typically displays the source received from the server, not the current source.)

Comment: @user1691389 A CSS stylesheet always tests the attributes of the DOM elements. The same attributes can be accessed from Javascript. These attributes may (and will, in this case) differ from what the server sends in HTML

Comment: @JanDvorak, all fo your various answers helped me piece together various solutions; thanks, man.